# How get access to scene, renderer, camera objects Forge viewer v6 in TS

Tags: javascript, three.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

Previously I was able to use code like the following:

```
var container = viewer.canvas.parentElement;
var renderer = viewer.impl.renderer();
var scene = viewer.impl.scene;
```

to get access to the Three.js objects in Forge Viewer, now in v6 how can I do the same using TypeScript?

I alreday use the definitions of the Forge Viewer for TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Below tests were based on:
[image]

> var container = viewer.canvas.parentElement

Present in Viewer v6: [image]

> var renderer = viewer.impl.renderer();

Present in Viewer v6: [image]

> var scene = viewer.impl.scene;

Present in Viewer v6: [image]

Comment: This is not valid in Typescript.

Comment: Then you'd have let us know you were talking about typescript shouldn't you? Use the [typings for Forge viewer[(https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f527c7f10d6ea99e14e161dc01d231543645f95a/types/forge-viewer/README.md) then ... (except `impl.renderer` is not yet defined and you will need to add that to the definitions yourself for now)

Comment: Though you still don't have access to the mentioned methods/properties, should I define them?

Comment: Of course you have access - see live code [here](https://jsbin.com/tuneyec/edit?html) and my screenshots in the answer